# Theorem of dominated convergence

Tags: real-analysis

I need to prove :

$$ \int_{D} dw' \frac{\chi(w')}{w'-w-i \epsilon} \xrightarrow[\epsilon \to 0]{} \int_{D} dw' \frac{\chi(w')}{w'-w} $$

Where $D=[-\infty;w-p]$ and $D=[w+p;+\infty]$

But I don't know how to do this.

I want to apply the theorem of dominated convergence :

$$ |\frac{\chi(w')}{w'-w-i \epsilon}| \leq \frac{|\chi(w')|}{||w'-w|- \epsilon|}$$

But to apply the theorem of dominated convergence, I need to have a majoration independent of $\epsilon$.

As $\epsilon \to 0 $, I just need to find a nice $M$ where $\epsilon < M$ for which the majorating function will be integrable. But I don't find how to do it.

Could you help me ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have the answer but I would like your opinion about it.

I work on $D=[w+p; +\infty]$, $p$ is assumed positive, $\chi$ is assumed integrable.

Here : $w'-w>p$

So : 
$$||w'-w|-\epsilon|=|w'-w-\epsilon|$$

If I chose : $\epsilon<M$ with $M=p/2$, I have : $w'-w-\epsilon\geq w'-w-p/2 \geq p/2 > 0$.
So : $w'-w-\epsilon=||w'-w|-\epsilon|\geq |w'-w-p/2|$
So : $$ |\frac{\chi(w')}{||w'-w|-\epsilon|}|\leq g=|\frac{\chi(w')}{|w'-w-p/2|}|$$

And $g$ is integrable, so we can intervert.

An analog thing can be done for $[-\infty; -w-p]$.

Do you agree with my method ?